# SwiftUI: How to force SwiftUI ContextMenu Preview to take up the full Width?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, contextmenu

**Context**

I am currently working with the new `SwiftUI ContextMenu`, which supports a `Preview`. However, I have difficulties forcing the `Preview` to take up the full width of the screen.

---

**Code**

```swift
Text("Hello World")
    .contextMenu { menuItems } preview: { Text("Preview") }
```

---

**Question**

> **Please Note:** I already tried to add `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` to `Text("Preview")` but this didn't solve the problem.

- How can I force the Preview to take up the full width of the screen?

Answer (score 3):

You could wrap your preview view in a `NavigationStack`. That's easy, but it will not only expand the preview horizontally, it will also expand vertically, which may not be what you're looking for.

Another way would be to set the `idealWidth` for the preview:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var viewWidth = CGFloat.zero

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      VStack {
        Image(systemName: "globe")
          .imageScale(.large)
          .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
        Text("Long press me")
      }
      .contextMenu {
        Button("Action") {}
      } preview: {
        Text("Preview Text")
          .padding(.vertical, 50)
          .frame(idealWidth: viewWidth)
      }
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .overlay {
      GeometryReader { geometry in
        Color.clear
          .onAppear {
            self.viewWidth = geometry.frame(in: .local).size.height
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: NavigationStack solved this issue 

Answer (score 0):

This was deprecated.[image]

You didn't give much code, so I used random example:
You can use Menu like this:

```
struct MenuExample: View {

var body: some View {
    Menu {
        Button("Duplicate", action: duplicate)
        Button {
            rename()
        } label: { Label("rename", systemImage: "square.and.pencil") }
        Button {
            delete()
        } label: { Label("delete", systemImage: "trash") }
        
        Menu {
            Button("Open in Preview", action: openInPreview)
            Button("Save as PDF", action: saveAsPDF)
        } label: { Label("PDF", systemImage: "doc.fill") }
    } label: {
        Label("Menu", systemImage: "book.fill")
            .font(.title)
    }
    .foregroundColor(.orange)
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
    .padding(30)
    .background(.orange.opacity(0.3))
  }

    func duplicate() {}
    func delete() {}
    func rename() {}
    func saveAsPDF() {}
    func openInPreview() {}
}

struct MenuTemp_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    MenuExample()
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you please link to the documentation showing it's deprecated? I have the docs open right now and it says `contextMenu(menuItems:preview:)` is in beta for iOS 16.0

Comment: Oh you're right, I meant the one in the attached pic. I don't work on beta version yet so I missed that, sorry.

Comment: What is the function signature of the deprecated method?

Comment: You want the deprecated? I think it was:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/contextmenu(_:)